# Set the fastest mirror from preseed

Tags: apt, system-installation, preseed, mirrors

So, choosing the best mirror in the */etc/apt/sources.list* can be simply done by removing the country prefix before "*archive.ubuntu.com*" (i.e. "*us.*").

For a new installation, it should be possible to specify this instruction on the preseed file:

```
d-i mirror/http/mirror select archive.ubuntu.com
```

But for some reason, the installer ignores this line and keeps the prefix as the ISO-3166-2 country code, from the locale settings. This is not so optimum for standard installations with "us" locales connecting from somewhere else than US.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?
(I'm using Ubuntu server 16.04)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to get away with simply adding a mirror hostname:

```
d-i mirror/http/hostname string archive.ubuntu.com
```

I've been using the following mirror settings for a test preseed for a while, and it seems to work well enough for my purposes:

```
d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname string mirrors.us.kernel.org
d-i mirror/http/mirror select mirrors.us.kernel.org
d-i mirror/http/directory string /ubuntu
d-i mirror/http/proxy string
```