# fail to auto install ubuntu 16.04 with preseed.cfg,http not work

Tags: 16.04, preseed

fail to install ubuntu 16.04 with preseed.cfg

http protocol seems  not work in preseed file

version: ubuntu 16.04 server including server and client

when I set http protocol in the file preseed.cfg like bellow,

```
d-i mirror/protocol string http
#d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname string 192.168.18.81
d-i mirror/http/directory string /ubuntu/
d-i mirror/http/proxy string
```

the logs shows that it get the mirror/source from us.archive.com/ubuntu,

sometimes it is from  gb.archive.com/ubuntu or archive.com/ubuntu
which is not I set it up.

and it doest not go to wget the URL http://192.168.18.81/ubuntu which I set.

I try to change the protocol from http to ftp.
I found it work like I wish.
A part of preseed.cfg is like this:

```
d-i mirror/protocol string ftp
#d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/ftp/hostname string 192.168.18.81
d-i mirror/ftp/directory string /ubuntu/
d-i mirror/ftp/proxy string
```

I think it is a simple issues like

[Set the fastest mirror from preseed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800461/set-the-fastest-mirror-from-preseed/863395#863395)

Does the preseed does not support http? or anywhere I did wrong?

here is the total process.

apt-get install isc-dhcp-server -y

cat /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf |grep -v ^#|grep -v ^$

```
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
log-facility local7;
allow booting;
allow bootp;
subnet 192.168.18.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
       range 192.168.18.50 192.168.18.100;
       option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
       option routers 192.168.18.1;
       option domain-name-servers 223.5.5.5;  
       option broadcast-address 10.255.255.255;
       filename "pxelinux.0";
       next-server 192.168.18.81;
}
```

apt-get install tftp-hpa

cat /etc/default/tftpd-hpa

```
# /etc/default/tftpd-hpa

TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/var/lib/tftpboot"
TFTP_ADDRESS=":69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure
```

```
apt-get install apache2 -y
mount iso/ubuntu-16.04.6-server-amd64.iso /var/www/html/ubuntu
cp -r /var/www/html/ubuntu/install/netboot/* /var/ftpd/
service apache2 start
```

cat /var/ftpd/pxelinux.cfg/default

```
# D-I config version 2.0
# search path for the c32 support libraries (libcom32, libutil etc.)
path ubuntu-installer/amd64/boot-screens/
include ubuntu-installer/amd64/boot-screens/menu.cfg
default ubuntu-installer/amd64/boot-screens/vesamenu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 3
```

cat /var/ftpd/ubuntu-installer/amd64/boot-screens/txt.cfg

```
default install
label install
    menu label ^Install
    menu default
    kernel ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux
    append initrd=ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz ramdisk_size=100000 auto=true priority=critical interface=auto netcfg/no_default_route=true preseed/url=http://192.168.18.81/preseed.cfg BOOT_DEBUG=2 
label cli
    menu label ^Command-line install
    kernel ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux
    append tasks=standard pkgsel/language-pack-patterns= pkgsel/install-language-support=false vga=788 initrd=ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz --- quiet
```

Answer (score 0):

Preseeding does support the http protocol. In fact, it should support any question asked by the installer and all of them may be answered with a seed file (some minor rare bugs here and there do exist depending on version and your `initrd`, but irrelevant here).

When questions are answered with a wrong / unsupported answer, the installer usually ignores your d-i stanza and lets the installer decide what to do (depending on your selected `priority` kernel parameter or manual choice within the installer).

Empty strings usually answer with an empty string or skip a question.

Looking at your mirror stanzas there seems to be a problem:

```
d-i mirror/protocol string http
#d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname string 192.168.18.81
d-i mirror/http/directory string /ubuntu/
d-i mirror/http/proxy string
```

- When using http, there is no need for a `d-i mirror/protocol` stanza - http is the default. [Debian's preseed documentation](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/apbs04.en.html) in section **B.4.4. Mirror settings** comments this stanza.
- Regarding your repository location issue: you have commented the critical `d-i mirror/country` stanza - it is only allowed when using the ftp protocol:

> **If you select ftp, the mirror/country string does not need to be set.**

So your installer ignores the mirror selection when using http, and chooses one of its defaults. When doing so, it ignores the `hostname` and `directory` stanzas as the relevant questions were never asked by the installer.
**If you would like to use your own repo**, **do not comment this line** - leave it as `string manual`.

Overall your mirror section should look something like this:

```
d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname string 192.168.18.81
d-i mirror/http/directory string /ubuntu/
```

Some resources to help you understand and use preseeding better:

[Official Debian documentation for preseeding](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/apb.en.html)

An official preseed example file with almost every parameter available documented by Debian: [Debian 10 (buster)](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/example-preseed.txt). Debian 10 is the latest release.